# Encontrar mais de um padrao re python?

Tags: python, regex

Estou tentanto renomear arquivos utilizando regex em python, com apenas um padrao funciona:

```
def new_string(pattern):
    text = pattern.group().lower()
    renturn "{}_{}".format(text[0], text[1])

regex = re.compile(r"[a-z][A-Z]")
for x in files:
    print(regex.sub(new_string, x))
```

Mas quero substituir tambem outros padroes:

```
r"[a-zA-Z][0-9]"
```

Como fazer para encontrar os dois padroes ao inves de um so?

Comment: Encontrei a solução usando |

Comment: Você pode responder sua própria pergunta descrevendo a solução de forma detalhada, pra ajudar outros que futuramente tenham o mesmo problema.

Comment: sim, a resposta correta é usando o operador "|" de expressões regulares.
Agora você tem a opção de escrever uma resposta a sua própria pergunta (incluindo um exemplo,etc...), de forma que sua dúvida possa ajudar outras pessoas no futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema assim:

```
def replace(pattern):
    text = pattern.group().lower()
    renturn "{}_{}".format(text[0], text[1])

regex = re.compile(r"([a-z][A-Z])|([a-z][0-9])")
    for x in files:
    print(regex.sub(replace, x))
```

Utilizando o operador `|` (ou) ele vai testar os dois padrões